# Display works for a few seconds, but then tells me there is no signal

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, monitoring

my new Raspberry Pi has been acting up a bit lately. The first time I plugged it in, I had all of the neccisary parts, as well as a 8 GB SD card that had been formatted and filled with the "NOOBS" stuff. I would plug in the Pi, and it would work for a few minutes. It showed the it had me choose between Raspbian, Raspbian with Scratch boot or something like that. I chose rasbian, and it would begin to install it. I looked away at my laptop for a few minutes, then looked back over and the monitor (and the TV that I am trying now) would say No signal. The first time both the red and green lights on the pi were on, but the second time only the red light shone. Now I am getting ready to go for the third time.

Any help is appreciated!

-Danny

-After the third try:
Took a video this time, looks like it crashed while "Extracting Filesystem". It looked to be at about 13% when the screen went black and showed the "no signal" sign.  BTW i am using raspberry pi 2 model B

Answer (score 1):

Your power supply is probably at fault. The raspberry Pi 2 needs a solid power supply, ideally 5V 2A or more (depending on what you are powering from the Pi, like USB dongles, keyboards, HDMI monitors etc).

Comment: Thanks! I am trying it with a 5V 2A charger that I spent most of the morning looking for. I will reply how it works!

Comment: Note that cellphone chargers MIGHT work - but their Amp ratings are often peak Amps and not sustained. Best is to buy a power supply specifically designed for the raspberry Pi 2, such as [this one](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/28-17985).